# Cannot create .xlsx file in Octave 3.8.2

Tags: matlab, io, octave

I have just switched from `Matlab` to `Octave` 3.8.2 and spending a lot of hours to rewrite my programs.

The issue I am currently having is related to io pkg's xlswrite function.

In the code I have implemented, my Matlab code would search a directory for an .xlsx file with a given name. If there was such a file, it would change the filename to filename_v2 and write data in it , else it would create it first and then write data in it.

However, Octave doesn't seem to work this way.

Actually, whenever I am trying to create a file using xlswrite function I get the following error:

`error: xlsopen.m: file filename.xlsx not found`

Any idea how I could go round this problem?

Thank you very much in advance.

Kostas

EDIT: I am using Windows 7 and the exact code is:

```
if exist('Data Logger.xlsx','file')==0
     name='Data Logger.xlsx';
else
     found=1;
     v=1;
     while found==1
          v=v+1;
          name_cand=strcat('Data Logger_v',num2str(v),'.xlsx');
          if exist(name_cand,'file')==0
               found=0;
          end     
     end 
     name=name_cand;
end  
xlswrite(name,Header)
```

Comment: What code do you use to call xlswrite?

Comment: There are different backends to read/write xlsx files http://wiki.octave.org/IO_package. Which one do you use? Show some code! Are you on GNU/Linux or windoze?

Comment: Thank you Daniel. It seems that the problem was the space between Data and Logger in the filename. I know it was bad practice to use a space in the filename but used to work just fine in Matlab. Thank you for your time anyhow ;)

Answer (score 3):

Solved: Its seems that Octave does not accept spaces in filenames.

Changed Data Logger.xlsx to Data_Logger.xlsx and everything worked perfectly

Thank you all for your willingness to help.

Cheers, Kostas